# How to work with WebElement which change in runtime?

Tags: c#, selenium

I got his code to wait until control found

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var ok = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("(//button[@id='btnOkDialog'])[" + buttonOccuranceNo + "]")));
```

I use this when some control take place in dom after any event.

Now if I reduce scope of search in page [Like taking a div inside WebDriver, which is a WebElement] then how do I search any control within that scope until its found or timeout occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a different wait, using the `DefaultWait` class:

```
var waitInnerScope = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(divInsideWebDriver);
waitInnerScope.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
waitInnerScope.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
```

Then use with `wait.Until`:

```
var ok = waitInnerScope.Until(PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("(//button[@id='btnOkDialog'])[" + buttonOccuranceNo + "]")));
```

**EDIT**: Since `ExpectedConditions` consists of static methods that implement `Func<IWebDriver, ...>` for the use with `WebDriverWait`, you'll have to use your own method that takes an `IWebElement` as so:

```
public static Func<IWebElement, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
{
    return (element) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var elements = element.FindElements(locator);
            return elements.Any() ? elements : null;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Or you can use a lambda expression for an anonymous method like so:

```
waitInnerScope.Until<ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>((element) => 
{
    try
    {
        var elements = element.FindElements(By.XPath("(//button[@id='btnOkDialog'])[" + buttonOccuranceNo + "]"));
        return elements.Any() ? elements : null;
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
    {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: ExpectedConditions contain all method with Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> or bool > return tye function. So its generating error. Is there any class which have method return Func<IWebElement, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> or bool >?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you asked, please try to clarify

Comment: I try your suggession and got error in ExpectedConditions class. When I go inside of that class I found all methods declare in that class has Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>) or Func<IWebDriver, bool) as return type.

Comment: Continue: Untill() method took parameters typeof DefaultWait and TResult. So as I pass IWebElement as type of DefaultWait, Untill() will take IWbelEment And TResult as parameter type which  not provided by ExpectedConditions.